# MapView regionThatFits set using horizontalAccuracy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, cllocation

I'm looking for a method to convert meters to a mapview region.

`CLLocation`'s `horizontalAccuracy` is a double, representing the accuracy in meters. `regionThatFits:` takes an `MKCoordinateRegion` which has a `span` with `longitudeDelta` and `latitudeDelta`. How can I convert meters to a longitude/latitude span?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer. It seems that 1 degree of latitude is equal to around 111 kilometers, or 111120 meters

```
- (MKCoordinateRegion)regionForAccuracyOfLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{
    CLLocationDegrees spanInDegrees = (CLLocationDegrees) (location.horizontalAccuracy / 222240);

    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanInDegrees, spanInDegrees) ;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span);

    return region;
}
```